# How to call stored procedure in ActionResult Entity Framework Web API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to execute a stored procedure in `ActionResult` to return it as json format. My stored procedure name is `db.SpCategoriesRead`, and I need to pass these parameters : ("1.1", 0, 0, "")

I am new to Entity Framework, I did it using direct commands but ones I replaced it with stored procedure it is not working.

Here is my code :

```
public ActionResult cats()
{
        bool isValid = false;
        string authToken = "";

        if (Request["dt"] != null)
            authToken = Request["dt"].ToString().Trim();
        else
            return Content("{\"error\":\"Please send device token parameter 'dt'.\"}", "application/json");

        string message = (new CommonFunction()).ValidateToken(authToken, out isValid);

        if (isValid)
        {
            var q = db.SpCategoriesRead("1.1", 0, 0, "");

            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            //var q = db.Categories.Where(p => !p.ParentCategoryID.HasValue && p.StatusID.Equals(1));
            if (q.Count() < 1)
                return Content("{\"error\":\"No results found.\"}", "application/json");

            return Json(q.OrderBy(cat => cat.SortOrder).Select(c => new { c.CategoryID, c.CatName, c.IconFile, LogoFile = string.Concat("white-", c.LogoFile) }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("{\"error\":\"" + message + "\"}", "application/json");
        }
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: it will stopped here if (q.Count() < 1)

System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: FYI: Do not return JSON, just an instance of a response class. The serialization (JSON, XML) is done by ASP.NET itself